# Migration from Weblogic 10.3.5 to tomcat for liferay 6.1 EE

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, liferay-6, portal

I am trying to migrate my application which is liferay 6.1 EE from weblog to tomcat.
Can Anyone give me the steps?

Also One of my portlet uses weblogic.xml to load jar from application itself, What is alternative for weblogic.xml in tomcat?

Thanks,
Naresh kallamadi.

Comment: Drop WAR file into `webapps/`, fix all obvious errors logged to the log file. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: You'll find a lot of documentation when you compare the installation documentation for Liferay on Websphere and on Tomcat. However, stackoverflow is a site that has explicitly opted for "Can anyone give me the steps" - e.g. asking for documentation and tutorials - is out of scope here. If you describe a specific problem that you're running into, you might be able to get it in scope again. And your "weblogic.xml" question would need more details / code to be in scope. An xml file doesn't load a jar.